# PHP: Remove 'print/' from URL from end of a String

Tags: php, string, url, preg-replace

This code gives an URL for a QR Code, but I'm going to use it on the print version of the page, so I have to (preg_replace) remove 'print/' from the end of the url string, so the URL given, is for the non-print version. Please.

```
public function getPageUrl() {      
    $url = (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS'])) ? "https://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] : "http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    return $url;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public function getPageUrl() {
    $url = 'https://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

    if (empty($_SERVER['HTTPS'])) {
        $url = str_replace('https://', 'http://', $url);
    }

    return preg_replace('~/print/?$~i', '', $url);
}
```